# How to modify wp_config file for set up subdirectory?

Tags: multisite, wp-config

am not a programmer. currently creating a multisite on wordpress. I want to create a subdirectory. here's the code for subdomain. how can i change it for subdirectory.

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.mysite.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );` to `define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );`

More here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration

Comment: Thank you Rahul. I changed it myself as,/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDIRECTORY_INSTALL', true);
define('CURRENT_SITE_DIRECTORY', 'www.mysite.com');
define('CURRENT_SITE_PATH', '/');
define('CURRENT_SITE_SITE_ID', 1);
define('CURRENT_SITE_BLOG_ID', 1);